# Labelling automatically data with topics extracted with ldaseqmodel

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm using the ldaseqmodel for dynamic topic modeling. I would like to label which of the topics I have extracted with ldaseqmodel. So I used the ldaseq.doc_topics(doc_number) method to write the code by referring to the gensim(https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.html)

The data frame I want to create is as follows.

| year | text | topic | topic_porb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | abcd | 1 | 0.021233 |

And the code I came up with is this.

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

df['topic'] = 0
df['topic_prob'] = 0

for i in tqdm(range(len(df))):
    df['topic_prob'].iloc[i] = max(ldaseq.doc_topics(doc_number = i))
    df['topic'].iloc[i] = np.argmax(ldaseq.doc_topics(doc_number = i)) + 1
```

However, the data are not labeled with appropriate topics. I wonder what the problem is.
I want to put the topic number for df['topic'] and the topic probability for df['topic_prob'] in the DataFrame with each data.

1. Is there an error in my code?
2. In the case of LDA, I know that you can extract the topic and the probability of the topic through the lda.get_doc_topics() method, but I wonder if there is a method that works like that in the ldaseq model, and coding with ldaseq.doc_topics(doc_number) is the right thing to do.

LDA topic modeling has experience labeling topics using lda.get_document_topics(). But I'm not sure because it's my first time doing it with the ldaseqmodel. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Comment: Can you give you give an example of what your dataframe should look lie?

Comment: The columns of the data frame now have year, text. The year contains the year values of texts, and the text contains the document data that I used.
So there are a total of 10121 row, and there are two columns. I would like to add the topic and topic_prob columns here to put the topic number and the topic probability to which topic the data in the texts correspond.

Comment: An example of a data frame has been added and modified. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how :D